# C# examining and replacing tuple values based on other tuple

Tags: c#, recursion, tuples

I'm starting with programming and C# and I have two tuples. One tuple is representing a list of points:

```
static List<(string, string, string)> PR { get; set; } = new List<(string, string, string)>()
    {
        ("P1", "0", "0"),
        ("P2", "P1", "P1+Height"),
        ("P3", "P1+Width", "P2"),
        ("P4", "P3", "P3+Height")
    };
```

where Item1 in the list of tuples stands for a Point name (P1, P2, P3, P4) and Item2 and Item3 represent a parametric formula for respectively the x- and y-value of a point.

"P1" in the second item in the above list should look for the tuple starting with "P1", and then for the second item in that tuple, in this case, 0.

I have a second list of tuples that represent the parameters that I need to calculate the above point values.

```
static List<(string, double)> PAR { get; set; } = new List<(string, double)>()
    {
        ("Height", 500),
        ("Width", 1000)
    };
```

Say I want to calculate the value of the parametric formula "P3+Height" as follows:

P3+Height --> P2 (+Height) --> P1+Height (+Height) --> 0 (+Height (+Height) --> 0 + Height + Height;

In the end I want to replace the parameter strings with the actual values (0 + 500 + 500 -> P3+Height = 1000) but thats of later concern.

Question: I'm trying to make a function that recursively evaluates the list of tuples and keeps the parameter names, but also looks for the corresponding tuple until we reach an end or exit situation. This is where I'm at now but I have a hard time getting my thought process in actual working code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //inputString = "P3+Height"
        string inputString = PR[3].Item3;

        string[] returnedString = GetParameterString(inputString);


        #region READLINE
        Console.ReadLine();
        #endregion
    }

    private static string[] GetParameterString(string inputString)
    {
        string[] stringToEvaluate = SplitInputString(inputString);

        for (int i = 0; i < stringToEvaluate.Length; i++)
        {
            //--EXIT CONDITION
            if (stringToEvaluate[0] == "P1")
            {
                stringToEvaluate[i] = "0";
            }

            else
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    //Check if parameters[i] is point string
                    var value = PAR.Find(p => p.Item1.Equals(stringToEvaluate[i]));

                    //Check if parameters[i] is double string
                    if (double.TryParse(stringToEvaluate[i], out double result))
                    {
                        stringToEvaluate[i] = result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (value == default)
                    {
                        //We have a point identifier
                        var relatingPR = PR.Find(val => val.Item1.Equals(stringToEvaluate[i])).Item2;
                        
                        //stringToEvaluate[i] = PR.Find(val => val.Item1.Equals(pointId)).Item2;
                        stringToEvaluate = SearchParameterString(relatingPR);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //We have a parameter identifier
                        stringToEvaluate[i] = value.Item2.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return stringToEvaluate;
    }

    private static string[] SplitInputString(string inputString)
    {
        string[] splittedString;
        splittedString = Regex.Split(inputString, Delimiters);
        return splittedString;
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how this could be done with either recursion or some other, better, easier way?

In the end, I need to get a list of tuples like this:

```
("P1", "0", "0"),
("P2", "0", "500"),
("P3", "1000", "500"),
("P4", "1000", "1000")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey. Really complicated the way you are trying to do it. Any reason why you are not using a struct or a class that defines one entry of the tupple?

Comment: Hi, I think you need add more structure to your code as @AdrianEfford suggests, and also use a linked list or tree to hold the nodes. This will simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something that does this - I changed a bit of the structure to simplify the code and runtime, but it still returns the tuple you expect:

```
    // first I used dictionaries so we can search for the corresponding value efftiantly: 
    static Dictionary<string, (string width, string height)> PR { get; set; } =
        new Dictionary<string, (string width, string height)>()
    {
            { "P1", ("0", "0") },
            { "P2", ("P1", "P1+Height")},
            { "P3", ("P1+Width", "P2") },
            { "P4", ("P3", "P3+Height") }
    };

    static Dictionary<string, double> PAR { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
            { "Height", 500 },
            { "Width", 1000 }
        };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // we want to "translate" each of the values height and width values
        List<(string, string, string)> res = new List<(string, string, string)>();
        foreach (var curr in PR)
        {
            // To keep the code generic we want the same code to run for height and width- 
            // but for functionality reasons we need to know which it is - so sent it as a parameter.
            res.Add((curr.Key,
                    GetParameterVal(curr.Value.width, false).ToString(),
                    GetParameterVal(curr.Value.height, true).ToString()));
        }

        #region READLINE
        Console.ReadLine();
        #endregion
    }


private static double GetParameterVal(string inputString, bool isHeight)
{
    // for now the only delimiter is + - adapt this and the code when \ as needed
    // this will split string with the delimiter ("+height", "-500", etc..)
    string[] delimiters = new string[] { "\\+", "\\-" };
    string[] stringToEvaluate = 
        Regex.Split(inputString, string.Format("(?=[{0}])", string.Join("", delimiters)));

    // now we want to sum up each "part" of the string
    var sum = stringToEvaluate.Select(x =>
    {
        double result;
        int factor = 1;
        // this will split from the delimiter, we will use it as a factor, 
        // ["+", "height"], ["-", "500"] etc..
        string[] splitFromDelimiter=
            Regex.Split(x, string.Format("(?<=[{0}])", string.Join("|", delimiters)));
        if (splitFromDelimiter.Length > 1) {
            factor = int.Parse(string.Format($"{splitFromDelimiter[0]}1"));
            x = splitFromDelimiter[1];
        }

        if (PR.ContainsKey(x))
        {
            // if we need to continue recursively translate
            result = GetParameterVal(isHeight ? PR[x].height : PR[x].width, isHeight);
        }
        else if (PAR.ContainsKey(x))
        {
            // exit condition
            result = PAR[x];
        }
        else
        {
            // just in case we didnt find something - we should get here
            result = 0;
        }

        return factor * result;
    }).Sum();

    return sum;
}

    }
}
```

I didnt add any validity checks, and if a value wasn't found it recieves a val of 0, but go ahead and adapt it to your needs..

Comment: thanks for the help and the example you've provided. This one is a bit easier to understand. I can even have random parameter strings right?  I still have a question though: What if I want to be able to also use the '-' as an operator? How would that fit in? I would like to be able to also use that. In every case we can be sure the string to evaluate always starts with either a parameter name or a point reference to the PR dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by random parameter strings, but yes, PAR and PR can have as many and whatever values you'd like :) just remember that if something isn't found it''ll be regarded to as "0" - so be careful what you put in there (we could have thrown an exception or written a message, I'll leave that to you) :)

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. This needs to go into a bigger program that calculates point coordinates based on the two dictionaries. These points will be used to create a profile instance. That profile is used in another 3d construction software that generates 3d entities based on profile. I tested it locally in a console application and it all works perfectly. Thanks for now and I will move on to implement it in the bigger whole. Thanks again you both!

Comment: Sure :)  if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. of course there is no obligation to do this. 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**Here a a working example for your question... It took me a lot of time so I hope you appreciate it:** 
 The whole code is comented line by line. If you have any question do not hesitate to ask me !
 
First of all we create a class named `myEntry` that will represent an entry. The name has to be unique e.g P1, P2, P3

```
public class myEntry
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; } //this field should be unique
        public object Height { get; set; } //Can contain a reference to another entry or a value also as many combinations of those as you want. 
                                            // They have to be separated with a +

        public object Width { get; set; } //same as for height here

        public myEntry(string name, object height, object width)
        {
            //Set values
            this.Name = name;
            this.Height = height;
            this.Width = width;
        }
    }
```

Now I create a dummy Exception class for an exception in a further class (you will see the use of this further on. Just ignore it for now)

```
public class UnknownEntry : Exception
    {
        //Create a new Class that represents an exception
    }
```

Now we create the important class that will handle the entries and do all the work for us. This might look complicated but if you don't want to spend time understanding it you can just copy paste it, its a working solution!

```
public class EntryHolder
    {
        private Dictionary<string, double> _par = new Dictionary<string, double>(); //Dictionary holding our known variables

        private List<myEntry> _entries; //List holding our entries
        

        public EntryHolder()
        {
            _entries = new List<myEntry>(); //Create list

            //Populate dictionary
            _par.Add("Height", 500);
            _par.Add("Width", 1000);
        }

        public bool Add(myEntry entry)
        {
            var otherEntry = _entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(entry.Name)); //Get entry with same name
            if(otherEntry != null)
            {
                //Entry with the same name as another entry

                //throw new DuplicateNameException(); //Throw an exception if you want
                return false; //or just return false
            }

            //Entry to add is valid
            _entries.Add(entry); //Add entry
            return true; //return success
        }

        public void Add(List<myEntry> entries)
        {
            foreach (var entry in entries) //Loop through entries
            {
                Add(entry);
            }
        }

        public myEntry GetEntry(string uniqueName)
        {
            var entry = GetRawEntry(uniqueName); //Get raw entry

            var heightToCalculate = entry.Height.ToString(); //Height to calculate to string
            var widthToCalculate = entry.Width.ToString(); //Width to calculate to string

            entry.Height = Calculate(heightToCalculate, true); //Calculate height
            entry.Width = Calculate(widthToCalculate, false); //Calculate width
            return entry; //return entry
        }

        public List<myEntry> CalculateAllEntries()
        {
            List<myEntry> toReturn = new List<myEntry>(); //Create list that we will return after the calculation finished
            foreach (var entryToCalculate in _entries) //Loop through all entries
            {
                toReturn.Add(GetEntry(entryToCalculate.Name)); //calculate entry values and add them to the list we will return after
            }

            return toReturn; //return list after the whole calculation finished
        }

        private double Calculate(string toCalculate, bool isHeight)
        {
            if (!toCalculate.Contains("+"))
            {
                //String doesn't contain a + that means it has to be a number or a key in our dictionary
                object toConvert = toCalculate; //Set the object we want to convert to double

                var entryCorrespondingToThisValue = _entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(toCalculate)); //Check if the string is a reference to another entry
                if (entryCorrespondingToThisValue != null)
                {
                    //It is the name of another object
                    toConvert = isHeight ? entryCorrespondingToThisValue.Height : entryCorrespondingToThisValue.Width; //Set object to convert to the height or width of the object in entries
                }

                try
                {
                    return Convert.ToDouble(toConvert); //try to convert and return if success
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //the given height object has the wrong format 
                    //Format: (x + Y + z ...)
                    throw new FormatException();
                }
            }

            //Contains some +

            var spitedString = toCalculate.Split(new char[] {'+'}); //Split
            double sum = 0d; //Whole sum

            foreach (var splited in spitedString) //Loop through all elements
            {
                double toAdd = 0; //To add default = 0

                if (_par.ContainsKey(splited)) //Check if 'splited' is a key in the dictionary
                {
                    //part of object is in the par dictionary so we get the value of it
                    toAdd = _par[splited]; //get value corresponding to key in dictionary
                }
                else
                {
                    //'splited' is not a key in the dictionary

                    object toConvert = splited; //set object to convert

                    var entryCorrespondingToThisValue = _entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(splited)); //Does entries contain a reference to this value
                    if (entryCorrespondingToThisValue != null)
                    {
                        //It is a reference
                        toConvert = isHeight ? entryCorrespondingToThisValue.Height : entryCorrespondingToThisValue.Width; //Set to convert to references height or width
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        toAdd = Convert.ToDouble(toConvert); //Try to convert object
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //A part of the given height is not a number or is known in the par dictionary
                        throw new FormatException();
                    }
                }
                
                sum += toAdd; //Add after one iteration
            }
            return sum; //return whole sum
        }
        

        public myEntry GetRawEntry(string uniqueName)
        {
            var rawEntry = _entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(uniqueName)); //Check for entry in entries by name (unique)
            if (rawEntry == null)
            {
                //Entry is not in the list holding all entries
                throw new UnknownEntry(); //throw an exception
                return null; //Or just return null
            }

            return rawEntry; //return entry
        }
    }
```

And here the end, the test and prove that it works:

```
public void TestIt()
    {
        List<myEntry> entries = new List<myEntry>()
        {
            new myEntry("P1", 0, 0),
            new myEntry("P2", "P1", "P1+Height"),
            new myEntry("P3", "P1+Height", "P2"),
            new myEntry("P4", "P3", "P3+Height"),

        };

        EntryHolder myEntryHolder = new EntryHolder();
        myEntryHolder.Add(entries);
        var calculatedEntries = myEntryHolder.CalculateAllEntries();
    }
```

**Here an image of how it looks like:** 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. I tried your code and it works indeed with my (mistakingly) short example of what I wanted to do. I do want to point out that I'm still a beginner and with the code you provided, I tried to work it out by typing out your solution but it's still a bit hard for me to understand. Also I'm trying to work this out in a way that the parameter names can be any random string. So Width could be WallWidthTop or something like that. Also I'm trying to be able to use either + or - operators to calculate the values. For now I want to thank you for the wonderful help though!

Comment: @Joop you are welcome. If you want to use - just use + a negative value ! :) e.g P1+-10

Comment: @Joop You can also add as many values as you want in the dictionary named _par in the constructor of the class EntryHolder and it will work for it self